# Clearing publication content from server

Tags: meteor

I am using the "low-level" publication API to publish a temporary collection (not backed by MongoDB).
The published collection is an homemade aggregation which depends on various persistent collections.

Due to business logic, at some point when I want to clear the published collection. This would mean calling `this.removed('my-collection', id)` for every item in the collection. However I don't want to maintain the list of item in the collection (this would probably be redundant with internal meteor cache anyway).

Is there a simple way to clear a collection from the server's publish code?

Comment: Depending on how you manage your subscriptions. If you use component-level subscriptions, they clear automatically if the component is unmounted, etc. Otherwise it kind be pretty tricky.